# How to log windbgx.exe output to a file?

Tags: powershell, cmd, windbg

In this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/windbg-command-line-preview) it says that the following command should log the output to a file:

```
WinDbgX.exe logo ".\myfile.txt"
```

However the windbg tells me that the debugger cannot find the file specified. I did run the command from powershell where `myfile.txt` is located so im not sure what the correct syntax is. I also tried other variants such as:

```
WinDbgX.exe "logo .\aaa.txt"
```

I also tried passing the parameter after specifying a particular imagine file to debug:

```
windbgx.exe myapp.exe logo myfile.txt
```

Comment: Is that something powershell specific? Can you run it in cmd?

Comment: It's not. I also tried from cmd.

Comment: Did you tried full path of the file? I think ".\" will be a working directory of windbg, not powershell's

Comment: From PS I tried: WinDbgX.exe .\myapp.exe logo "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\aaa.txt" and I don't get an error anymore. However nothing is logged to my text file after I break into my program and use some debugger commands just to test. The first line of the command window that appears when the debugger launch is this: CommandLine: .\myapp.exe logo C:\Users\myname\Desktop\aaa.txt

Comment: Do you see desired output on the terminal screen when you just run WinDbgX.exe .\myapp.exe ? If so you can use tee-object (in powershell) to redirect it to the file (do smth like WinDbgX.exe .\myapp.exe | tee-object "output.txt" )

Comment: I tried Tee-Object but nothing gets printed to the file. Maybe im just misunderstanding what the logo option is supposed to print. I thought its supposed to print the output of the command window but maybe not.

Comment: Well, tee supposed to get standard output from the command and then print and put it on the file. If you see nothing on your screen then nothing will be added to the file.

Comment: Possible typo in the documentation. Try `-logo` with a leading hyphen. Without the hyphen, it looks like you're trying to debug a program called `logo`.

Comment: In PS I just tried: WinDbgX.exe .\myapp.exe -logo "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\aaa.txt" and still nothing is being printed to aaa.txt. Does -logo work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log options seem to be unavailable in WinDbg Preview (WinDbgX) version 1.0.1810.02001, as well as some others like `/update`.

Even `/?` and `-?` do not display the list of available commands. Instead it runs invisible with 100% CPU on one logical core.

As an alternative, run `-c ".logopen myfile.txt"` to open a log file at the initial breakpoint.

---

The "old" WinDbg (non-Preview) uses `-logo` with a hyphen. Since you tried `WinDbgX.exe .\myapp.exe -logo "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\aaa.txt`, let me note that the executable needs to be the last parameter on the WinDbg command line.

If you pass anything behind the executable, that will be passed as parameters to that executable:

> *executable*
>
> Specifies the command line of an executable process. This is used to launch a new process and debug it. This has to be the final item on the command line. All text after the executable name is passed to the executable as its argument string.

Comment: This makes sense to me, however I just tried `WinDbgX.exe -logo "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\aaa.txt" "C:\Users\myname\myapp.exe"` and when windbg opens I get the error `Couldn't process command line parameters: Unrecognized command line option: logo
`